how to deal with seasonality in spatio-temporal kriging?
I'm currently working with a spatio temporal dataset of PM10 in North Italy, I have 4 years of weekly data and 160 stations on the region. I seasonally adjusted the time series of each station one by one and applyied Spatio temporal kriging on the residual on a grid all over the region of interest. T
he problem is that i want to add again on the prediction grid the seasonal component, how can i add the seasonal component on points of the grid between two station?
I only have time series and a seasonal model for the stations and not for the points of the prediction grid all over the region.
is There a standard procedure to deal with seasonality in this context?

Very generally--after all, one cannot be specific in responding to such a general question--you need to krige (or otherwise predict) the seasonal component, too.  You will have to confront the possibility that the seasonal component is correlated with the residuals: that's worth testing.  It would imply you need to krige the full vector-valued response.  Perhaps special features of your data will permit simplifications, such as fitting a common seasonal term to all time series rather than separate terms for each one.  More details would be welcome.

Thank you very much for your answer,  i've tried to fit a common seasonal model but it doesn't seem to work very well beacause for example stations in the Alps shows a very different seasonal pattern of the PM10 compared to large city such as Milan

(+1 to whuber suggestion but...) Is there a reason as to why you can't have three dimensions (lat-lon-week) as your space? You would then estimate the covariance kernel against all three. Length scale don't need to be the same across all and especially if a composite kernel is used, we can capture very different signals. (+1 on the question too, it's fun)
